# In React FullCallendar, How to make resource timeline week view horizontally scrollable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm currently using React FullCalendar with the resourceTimelineWeek view, and I'm facing an issue where the content doesn't fit within the available space, causing it to be cut off. I want to make the resource timeline week view horizontally scrollable to ensure all content is accessible.

FullCalendar ResourceTimeLineWeek View

[image]

here's the code:

```
<FullCalendar
titleFormat={{ year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" }}
views={{
    resourceTimeGridWeek: {
        type: "resourceTimeGrid",
        duration: { days: 7 },
    },
}}
datesAboveResources={true}
dayHeaderFormat={{ weekday: "long", meridiem: "long" }}
schedulerLicenseKey={process.env.REACT_APP_FULLCALENDAR_LICENSE_KEY}
ref={calendarRef}
plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, adaptivePlugin, resourceTimeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, rrulePlugin]}
headerToolbar={{
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title",
    right: "resourceTimeGrid,resourceTimeGridWeek,listWeek",
}}
initialView="resourceTimeGrid"
slotDuration="00:30:00"
slotMinTime={"06:00:00"}
slotMaxTime={"22:00:00"}
resourceAreaWidth="10%"
resources={resources}
resourceAreaHeaderContent="Classrooms"
events={sessions}
contentHeight={"auto"}
timeZone="UTC"
buttonText={{
    today: "Today",
    week: "Weekly",
    listWeek: "List",
    day: "Day",
    prev: "Prev",
    next: "Next",
    resourceTimelineDay: "Daily",
}}
```

/>

Comment: It's horizontally scrollable by default (see the [demos](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-standard-view-demo) on the fullcalendar website), so we'd have to guess you've done something which constrains it, perhaps using CSS or one of the fullcalendar display settings. Can you provide a [mre] of the issue please? We cannot usually fix pictures alone. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, even in the demo, it has the same problem in demo of Vertical resource view with datesAboveResources, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesAboveResources-demo

Comment: I don't see any problem when I visit that demo. Maybe you are viewing it on a very small screen? I am on a fairly small laptop and it looks fine.

Comment: yes but if you resize it to very small window you can see my case which is I have many resources.

Comment: OK. But it simply isn't designed to work with very small windows. Fullcalendar is not optimised for mobile devices etc. The makers of the project freely admit this. So if you are getting down to very small screens I don't think there is much you can do about it, unfortunately.

Comment: I managed to solve it by adding the plugin scrollgridPlugin

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't aware that with React you have to install each plugin separately - in vanilla JS that isn't needed. Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the plugin `scrollgridPlugin` by running this command:

```
npm i --save @fullcalendar/scrollgrid
```